# FFmpeg switch source RTSP in one contaier

Tags: ffmpeg, switch, input, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to switch the rtsp input of two ipcam into the capture of a single mp4 file.

At the moment I'm listening to:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:20000 -c:v copy -an out.mp4
```

While in a loop:

```
  while:
  do
         ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.5.23/av1_0 -f h264 -c:v copy -an -t 5 udp://127.0.0.1:20000

         ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.5.24/av1_0 -f h264 -c:v copy -an -t 5 udp://127.0.0.1:20000

  done
```

The out.mp4 file is generated correctly, but some frames are corrupted during the switch.

Doing a check with the command:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i out.mp4 -f null -
```

I get the errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x213c740] error while decoding MB 54 49, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0x213c740] error while decoding MB 83 56, bytestream -15
[h264 @ 0x213c740] error while decoding MB 0 55, bytestream -7
[h264 @ 0x213c740] error while decoding MB 3 65, bytestream -14
[h264 @ 0x213c740] error while decoding MB 114 51, bytestream -13
```

If instead I do not interrupt the rtsp flow of an ipcam the errors do not appear and the video is perfect.

Where am I wrong? Maybe it's the wrong method?
Thanks in advance